# Как сделать визуализатор аудио на js?

Tags: javascript

Надо сделать визуализатор музыки: столбцы, высота которых бы менялась в зависимости от частоты. Как это сделать на js?

Comment: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API но работать будет далеко не  везде.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да тут вообще много всего понаписано.
Попробуйте например [dancer.js](https://github.com/jsantell/dancer.js),
даже есть по настоящему красивые [результаты](http://jsantell.github.io/dancer.js/#).

Можете посмотреть здесь куча [рекомендаций](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351147/html5-audio-visualizer)

Comment: Спасибо, подошло